# Add multiple items to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to map my events from an api fetch, and add each event to the `dots` array for each day:

```
 case "EVENTS_SUCCESS":
            const events = {};
            const dayEvents = [];
            action.data.events.map(event => {
                const {
                    year: startYear,
                    month: startMonth,
                    day: startDay,
                    hour: startHour,
                    minutes: startMinute
                } = event.start_date_details;
                const {
                    hour: endHour,
                    minutes: endMinute
                } = event.end_date_details;

                const startDate = `${startYear}-${startMonth}-${startDay}`;
                const startTime = `${startHour}-${startMinute}`;
                const endTime = `${endHour}-${endMinute}`;

                let newEvent = {
                    key: event.title,
                    name: event.title,
                    color: "blue",
                    selectedDotColor: "white",
                    categories: event.categories,
                    startTime: startTime,
                    endTime: endTime
                };

                events[startDate] = {
                    // add newEvent dots array if startdate is same day
                    dots: [newEvent],
                    disabled: false
                };
            });

            return {
                ...events
            };
```

So my data will be:

```
{
"16-3-2018": {
     dots: [{key: 'blah', title: 'blah' ...},
            {key: 'blah', title: 'blah' ...}]
     disabled: false
}
}
```

However, I can only ever get one event in the `dots` array. How can I insert multiple events for the same day to the array?

Sample json:

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "id":516,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=516",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=516"
         ],
         "author":"2",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2017-12-14 12:00:37",
         "date_utc":"2017-12-14 12:00:37",
         "modified":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
         "modified_utc":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/test-event\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/516",
         "title":"testevent",
         "description":"<p>RG media team meetiNg to discuss anything and everything<\/p>",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":false,
         "start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-04-24 17:00:00",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"04",
            "day":"24",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-04-24 16:00:00",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"04",
            "day":"24",
            "hour":"16",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":true,
         "show_map_link":true,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"firm1",
               "slug":"firm1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":59,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":60,
               "count":4,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":59,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/59",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories",
                  "up":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60"
               }
            },
            {
               "name":"year 1",
               "slug":"year-1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":60,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":3,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":60,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories"
               }
            }
         ],
         "tags":[
            {
               "name":"tester",
               "slug":"tester",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":57,
               "taxonomy":"post_tag",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":1,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":57,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags\/57",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags"
               }
            }
         ],
         "venue":{
            "id":542,
            "author":"2",
            "status":"publish",
            "date":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
            "date_utc":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
            "modified":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
            "modified_utc":"2018-01-24 15:16:25",
            "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/venue\/medical-photography\/",
            "venue":"Medical Photography",
            "show_map":true,
            "show_map_link":true,
            "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=542",
            "global_id_lineage":[
               "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=542"
            ]
         },
         "organizer":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":538,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=538",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=538"
         ],
         "author":"2",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2018-01-21 16:36:32",
         "date_utc":"2018-01-21 16:36:32",
         "modified":"2018-01-21 16:40:13",
         "modified_utc":"2018-01-21 16:40:13",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/testing-again\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/538",
         "title":"testing again",
         "description":"",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":false,
         "start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-02-14 17:00:00",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-02-14 17:00:00",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":true,
         "show_map_link":true,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"firm1",
               "slug":"firm1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":59,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":60,
               "count":4,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":59,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/59",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories",
                  "up":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60"
               }
            },
            {
               "name":"year 1",
               "slug":"year-1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":60,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":3,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":60,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories"
               }
            }
         ],
         "tags":[

         ],
         "venue":[

         ],
         "organizer":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":544,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=544",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=544"
         ],
         "author":"2",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2018-02-07 10:20:19",
         "date_utc":"2018-02-07 10:20:19",
         "modified":"2018-02-07 10:20:49",
         "modified_utc":"2018-02-07 10:20:49",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/matts-birthday\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/544",
         "title":"matts birthday",
         "description":"<p>matts birthday<\/p>",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":false,
         "start_date":"2018-03-16 08:00:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"03",
            "day":"16",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-03-16 17:00:00",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"03",
            "day":"16",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-03-16 08:00:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"03",
            "day":"16",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-03-16 17:00:00",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"03",
            "day":"16",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":true,
         "show_map_link":true,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"firm1",
               "slug":"firm1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":59,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":60,
               "count":4,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":59,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/59",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories",
                  "up":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60"
               }
            },
            {
               "name":"year 1",
               "slug":"year-1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":60,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":3,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":60,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/60",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories"
               }
            }
         ],
         "tags":[

         ],
         "venue":[

         ],
         "organizer":[

         ]
      }
   ],
   "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/?page=1&per_page=10&start_date=2018-02-07 23:59:00&end_date=2020-02-08 08:56:30",
   "total":"3",
   "total_pages":1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are overriding it each time.
Try the following:

```
//...
events[startDate] = events[startDate] || {dots: []};

events[startDate] = {
  // add newEvent dots array if startdate is same day
  dots: [...events[startDate].dots, newEvent],
  disabled: false
};
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event by pushing it to the dots array:

```
events[startDate].dots.push(newEvent);
```

If you access the dots attribute directly you have to initialize it when you create events[startDate]. Like:

```
if (!events[startDate]) {
    events[startDate] = {dots: [], disabled = false}
}
```